# Bind dynamic Vue image src from node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, node-modules, vue-loader

I' am creating a Vue component that shows an SVG image from my node modules based on a given image name or key (given by an API).

If I put the source image directly like `~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/eur.svg`, the resource loads.

But if I try to compute it with the props or by the mounted method asigning it using `:src="imageSource"` it does not load.

I'm new to Vue so I don't know why is this happening? Should I use images downloaded in a public directory instead of the NPM package?

```
<template lang="html">
<img src="~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/eur.svg"  alt="icon" />
</template>

<script lang="js">
export default {
    name: 'crypto-icon',
    props: ['currency'],
    mounted() {
        this.imageSource = `~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${this.currency}.svg`
    },
    data() {
        return {
            imageSource: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getImageResource(){
            return `~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${this.currency}.svg`
        }
    },
    computed: {

    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.crypto-icon {}
</style>
```

Comment: Try out `this.imageSource = `require(~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${this.currency}.svg`)`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `require` attribute. Vue Loader, does this automatically when it compiles the `<template>` blocks in single file components. Try with this:

```
require(`~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${this.currency}.svg`)
```

You can read more [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html).

Comment: The `~` sign should be dropped when using `require()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by using a Vue plugin (see [vue-cryptoicons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cryptocurrency-icons)), although hatef is right about using `require` for image resources, using it in directories under `node_modules` tries to find the full path

```
~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"a7e19d86-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Wallet.vue?vue&type=template&id=7f1455a9&scoped=true&lang=html&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save ~cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color
```

Comment: Hmm that should have worked also under the [node directory](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules). Maybe it was cached? But, anyway it's not a good idea to read media from `node_modules` directory because you might end up updating the package and your media is gone.